# my image is not showing it's only showing the link on react table

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, react-table

Basically, I want to show images from API in react table. but it takes the image as a text. but I want to make it a visual image .so what should I do now?why it make as text.isn't it possible to show visual image .i have imported all the things perfectly
here is my code please give me suggestions:

```
import axios from 'axios';
import React, {
    useEffect,
    useState
} from 'react';
import {
    useTable
} from 'react-table/dist/react- 
table.development ';
import BTable from 'react-bootstrap/Table';
const ManageInventories = () => {
    const [ProductsItems, setProductsItems] = useState([]);
    useEffect(() => {
        const url = "http://localhost:5000/Inventory"
        axios.get(url)
            .then(res => setProductsItems(res.data))
    }, []);
    const data = React.useMemo(
        () => [...ProductsItems], [ProductsItems]);
    const columns = React.useMemo(
        () => ProductsItems[0] ? Object.keys(ProductsItems[0]).map((key) => {
            return {
                Header: key,
                accessor: key
            }
        }) : [],
        [ProductsItems]
    )
    const tableInstance = useTable({
        columns,
        data
    })
    const {
        getTableProps,
        getTableBodyProps,
        headerGroups,
        rows,
        prepareRow,
    } = tableInstance
    return ( <
        div >
        <
        BTable {
            ...getTableProps()
        }
        striped bordered hover size = "sm" >
        <
        thead > {
            headerGroups.map(headerGroup => ( <
                tr {
                    ...headerGroup.getHeaderGroupProps()
                } > {
                    headerGroup.headers.map(column => ( <
                        th {
                            ...column.getHeaderProps()
                        }
                        style = {
                            {
                                background: 'aliceblue',
                                color: 'black',
                                fontWeight: 'bold',
                            }
                        } >
                        {
                            column.render('Header')
                        } <
                        /th>
                    ))
                } <
                /tr>
            ))
        } <
        /thead> <
        tbody {
            ...getTableBodyProps()
        } > {
            rows.map(row => {
                prepareRow(row)
                return ( <
                    tr {
                        ...row.getRowProps()
                    } > {
                        row.cells.map(cell => {
                            return ( <
                                td {
                                    ...cell.getCellProps()
                                }
                                style = {
                                    {
                                        padding: '10px',
                                        border: 'solid 1px gray',
                                    }
                                } >
                                {
                                    cell.render('Cell')
                                } <
                                /td>
                            )
                        })
                    } <
                    /tr>
                )
            })
        } <
        /tbody> <
        /BTable> <
        /div>
    );
};
export default ManageInventories;
```

[Here is my output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HUUS4.png)

Comment: Please, indent your code so we can take a look at it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a special renderer for your image column.

https://react-table.tanstack.com/docs/api/useTable#column-options

I your columns list you should do something similar to:

```js
const columns = [
  ...otherColumns
  {
    Header: "Your header",
    accessor: "Your accessor",
    Cell: (props) => <img src={props.url} />,
  }

]
```

Comment: but i make my colomns vairable like this                                                                                         `const columns = React.useMemo(
        () => ProductsItems[0] ? Object.keys(ProductsItems[0]).map((key) => {
            if (key === "image") {
                return {
                    Header: key, accessor: key, Cell: ({ value }) => <img src={value} />

                }
            }


            return { Header: key, accessor: key, }
        }
        ) : [],
        [ProductsItems]
    )      `                       in this how can I use this?

Comment: I don't know exactly what your attributes are but that looks inline with what the docs have.